# Can I put my Bialetti stainless steel espresso maker in the dishwasher?

Tags: steel, stainless

I am wondering if there is any harm in putting my stainless steel Bialetti coffeemaker in the dishwasher. I don't think it should rust (because it's stainless steel). But I do wonder if the gasket will be able to take the heat of the dishwasher. I'm wondering if the heat will cause the gasket to wear out very rapidly.

I have run it through the dishwasher a few times and it looks beautiful when it comes out.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Dishwashing soap is pretty darn aggressive (e.g. it trashes aluminum), so unless the manufacturer says it's OK I'd be worried. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I second @DanielGriscom & wanted to note that silverware is stainless steel too, and there are articles upon articles discussing the damage dishwashers do to a sharp knife (for example). My guess is - it will work, but its lifespan will be shorter than if you washed it by hand. This is true for anything that goes in a DW. The seal would wear out faster too. (maybe it will last months, maybe years). If it doesn't say dishwasher safe, then a warranty often wont be honored under those circumstances.

Comment: Voting to close as [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (either operation of major appliances or related to small appliances). It's also clearly stated in the manufacturer's literature.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't deal with small appliance maintenance here

Answer (score 1):

According to the information I found online these are stove top pots. But the [care instructions](https://www.bialetti.com/coffee/stovetop/stainless-pots-c-1_7_21.html) say:

> - Wash by hand with warm water.
> - Dry with towel.
> - Do not reassemble until all parts are dry to avoid oxidation.
> - Do not use soap or detergent.    Do not use in dishwasher.
> - Do not use steel wool or other abrasives.

It sounds crazy but NO you can not according to the MFG. 
Added : even on the add on Amazon it states “Not dishwasher safe”.

Comment: How would you "use" it in the dishwasher?...

Comment: Ask the MFG that was from their site .